# NUCLEO STM32L432KC: How to use its DAC?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, dac

Another question yet again.

I am having troubles trying to use the DAC on the STLM32L432KC chip. Using PA_4 pin which only has DAC1 (Channel 1.) When I probe the pin nothing appears on it.

1. [Pinout](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-L432KC/)
2. [STMLM32L432KC Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00151940-stm32l41xxx42xxx43xxx44xxx45xxx46xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

Is there something that I over looked?

The code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "custom.h"
char buffer[80];
int adcValue = 0;
int counter = 0;

void ADC1_IRQHandler(void){

    if (((ADC1->ISR) & (1<<2)) != 0){
        adcValue = ADC1->DR;
        DAC1->DHR12R1 = adcValue;
        printADC(DAC1->DHR12R1);
        ADC1->ISR |= (1<<2);
    }
}



int main(void)
{

    initDebug();
    initADC();
    initDAC();

  while (1)
  {

  }


}


void printADC(int adcValue){

    sprintf(buffer, "ADC Value: [%d]\n\r",adcValue);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++){
         USART2->TDR = buffer[i]; //Put data in the Transmitter reg
         while(((USART2->ISR) & (1<<7)) == 0); //Wait till transmitter reg is empty
    }

}

void initDebug(){

    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (1<<17); // Enable USART2 Clock
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= (1<<0); //Enable GPIOA Clock
    RCC->CCIPR = (1<<2); //Use the System Clock for USART2

    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(1<<4); //Enable Alt Function for PA_2
    GPIOA->MODER |= (1<<5);
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= ((1<<10) | (1<<9) | (1<<8)); //Enable USART2_Tx for PA_2

    USART2->CR1 |= (1<<3); //Enable Transmitter
    USART2->BRR = 0x1A0; //9600 baudrate
    USART2->CR1 |= (1<<0); //Enable USART2

}

void initADC(){

    RCC->AHB2ENR |= ((1<<0) | (1<<13)); //Enable GPIOA Clock & ADC Clock
    RCC->CCIPR |= ((1<<29) | (1<<28)); //Uses System Clock for ADC

    GPIOA->MODER |= ((1<<15) | (1<<14)); //Enable Analog Mode for PA_7

    ADC1->CR &= ~(1<<29); //Disable Deep power ode
    ADC1->CR |= (1<<28); //Enable Voltage Regulator
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        counter += 1;
    }
    counter = 0;
    ADC1->CFGR |= (1<<13);
    ADC1->CR |= (1<<31); //Start Calbi
    while(((ADC1->CR) & (1<<31)) != 0);

    ADC1->IER |= (1<<2);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_IRQn,0);
    ADC1->SQR1 |= ((1<<9) | (1<<8));
    ADC1->ISR |= (1<<0);
    ADC1->CR |= (1<<0);
    while(((ADC1->ISR) & (1<<0)) == 0);
    ADC1->ISR |= (1<<0);
    ADC1->CR |= (1<<2);
}

void initDAC(){

    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (1<<29); // Enable Dac
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= (1<<0);
    GPIOA->MODER |= ((1<<9) | (1<<8));
    DAC1->MCR |= ((1<<1) | (1<<0));
    DAC1->CR |= (1<<0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        counter += 1;
    }
    counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see at the DAC pin? Is anything connected to the ADC? If the ADC input is 0, you will have 0V output at the DAC as well. And what is your counter-loop in the initDAC for? Depending on the compiler this loop probably is optimized out of the code, because it is not doing anything.

Comment: Well I expect an analog signal on the DAC pin. Yes, theres a Sine wave 60Hz 1VPP. The counter loop is just my ghetto delay. Noted in the datasheet as twakeup time.

Comment: Do you see the expected ADC results at your UART interface?

Comment: Yup. I can verify the ADC is working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the order I initiated my functions (initDebug, initADC, initDAC).

The problem was initiating the ADC function before the DAC function. There's interrupts within the ADC function as soon as the interrupts are enable and the IRQ gets put into work the DAC function never gets called.

The solutions would be initiating the DAC function first then the ADC or have a function call at the very end that enables all the IRQs.

Comment: Sorry, but that's either an inaccurate assessment or an indication that the ADC code is broken in more than just being called first.   The whole point of interrupts is that they don't prevent the processor from doing other things.  If they are, then they are being misused.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I am sorry for jumping to conclusions then. Do you see anything wrong in the ADC code then? Having to enable interrupts during setting up some registers is good then?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thats what I thought to. It would eventually come back to the main and finish off the rest of the code. Is there a way it could be a glitch if youre sampling rate is high (200kHZ+) ?

Comment: There should be no "eventually" with an ISR, unless your ISR is actually a pre-emptive scheduler or debugger hook, it must conclude its work essentially immediately.  If not, it trying to do something that an ISR should not be chosen to do.

Comment: I see, the way I figured it out is when I debugged it. I believe in debug mode Interrupts are disabled, so I just went on with that. In the actually code I move around the interrupt initialization and worked.